# Make an if for an event

Tags: javascript, if-statement, imasdk

i 'm trying to make an  IF.
If an ads event happens i have to do something but i dont know how to capture that event.

this is the code:

events:

```
player.ima.getAdsManager().addEventListener('loaded', function(){console.log('loaded')})
player.ima.getAdsManager().addEventListener('resume', function(){console.log('resume')})
player.ima.getAdsManager().addEventListener('complete', function(){console.log('completado')})
player.ima.getAdsManager().addEventListener('pause', function(){console.log('pausa')})
player.ima.getAdsManager().addEventListener('started', function(){console.log('started')})
```

i try this whit loaded event, but it dosen 't work..

```
if(player.ima.getAdsManager().addEventListener('loaded')){

}
```

How is it done?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can put whatever you want to do inside the function that gets triggered when that event occurs:

```
player.ima.getAdsManager().addEventListener('loaded', function(){
  // put your code here
})
```